# Drupal 6 custom career posting module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm attempting to build module that allows a user access to manage jobs/departments and post them to our website.  It will also allow end users to apply for a given position.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
About Us Page (standard drupal page)
  -Careers (overview with list of all openings)
    -Department Pages (if one or more jobs are available, they'll be displayed here)
      -Individual Job posting with form to submit resume
```

I am currently using two custom tables for jobs and departments.

I have all the administration (CRUD) stuff working just fine -- my question lies in the 'drupal' way of integrating the department pages and individual career pages.

Should I create a custom content type that stores all the job/department data in the node?  Or should I keep with my custom tables and integrate with the Path module to setup all the department pages and the application page? Also, what would be the best way to integrate the job application form into the module?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom node type for jobs and then create a taxonomy vocabulary for careers with terms for departments inside it so that you can then assign the taxonomy terms to a job.  That would be very quick and easy to do.

This also means that you could output nice categorised breadcrumbs using the Custom Breadcrumbs module.  Custom Breadcrumbs contains a submodule called Custom Breadcrumbs Taxonomy so you could output career/department information in the breadcrumbs.

You could also use Pathauto to output nicely structured SEO friendly URLS using this method.

Edited to say that with this method you could use Views to show taxonomy term specific lists simply by enabling the taxonomy term View, so you could show all openings at www.example.com/careers and all departmental openings at www.example.com/careers/department-name.